# Angular - Iterate over on response object from Google Books API

Tags: angular

Hello I'm new to angular and i'm working on Google Books API. Here I get object as response. As I'm new, I have no idea how to handle the object and display those on the screen. Please help me to fix this. Thank you.
**Please look at the console in the example**. [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/book-finder?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing anything in your typescript code, you can just iterate over the `items` property of your response and display any info you need.

Quick example (**app.component.html**):

```html
<div class="row">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>Publication Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let book of books.items">
        <td>{{book.accessInfo.country}}</td>
        <td>{{book.volumeInfo.title}}</td>
        <td>{{book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is a [Stackblitz with the changes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/book-finder-q4ej5t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).